# What’s C3103 error code does means for my car?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, yaris, lpg, mil

I have error code C3103 which reappear randomly every 30km to 50km. But absolutely no description attached beside C means chassis.

What does it means and what’s the additional steps to diagnoze ?

Comment: What year of Yaris again?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 sorry 2007.

Comment: I'm not finding anything associated with C3103 except some stupid website which seems to be posting BS just to get people on there and flash their ads at them. It obviously means *something*.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 except it lights the ᴍɪʟ so the car fails the vehicle inspection (or at least only internally).

Comment: Yup yup, no doubt.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 which prevents me register it and thus driving it legally.

Comment: What market are you in? C3103 isn’t used in the US. Verify the code with a different scanner.

Comment: @Ben I am in France.